# Finding minimum norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $A$ be $k\times k$ positive symmetric matrix, $K$ is $k\times d$ full rank matrix with $d<k$, and $v\in\mathbb{R}^k$.
I'd like to find $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $(Kx-v)^TA(Kx-v)$ minimum.

To do this, let $g(x)=(Kx-v)^TA(Kx-v)$. By letting $g'(x)=0 $  yields
\begin{equation}
K^TAKx-K^TAv+x^TK^TAK-v^TAK=0.
\end{equation}

But now, how can we find $x$ satisfying the above equation? Thanks for any help

Comment: Something is wrong because $x^T K^T A X$ is a row vector, and it's being added to column vectors.

Comment: I have rechecked my computation. It still produces the same formula

Answer (score 3):

Expanding $(Kx-v)^TA(Kx-v)$ gives

$$(x^TK^T-v^T)(AKx-Av)=x^TK^TAKx-x^TK^TAv-v^TAKx+v^TAv$$

Since $x^TK^TAv=v^TAKx$ you get the expression

$$x^TK^TAKx-2x^TK^TAv+v^TAv$$

Computing the derivative w.r.t. x and setting it to zero gives

$$2K^TAKx-2K^TAv=0$$

which results in the solution

$$x=(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TAv$$

Comment: How did you derive $K^TAKx+x^TK^TAK=2K^TAKx$?

Comment: That's not what I did. I used $x^TK^TAv = v^TAKx$. This works because both expressions are scalar.

Comment: Yes, but could you tell me how you derived that the derivative of $x^TK^TAKx-2x^TK^TAv+v^TAv$ w.r.t. to $x$ is $2K^TAKx-2K^TAv$?

Comment: In general, the derivative of $x^TQx$ w.r.t. $x$ is $2Qx$, and the derivative of $x^Tq$ is $q$, with $Q$ a fixed symmetric matrix, and $q$ a fixed (column) vector.

Comment: Check also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities